# Best way to show popup / notification through Iframe to its parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an Iframe in a page and some other page is opened in Iframe, now i want that a popup / notification or something else show on parent page on a event of the Iframe page.

Please share your comments!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As long as both page belong to you, you can use postMesaage() to communicate between frames. But you need to have access to both pages. See more details here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax with javascript to deploy pop-up message..Ajax to realize consult in the database and javascrip to deploy "alert message".

Answer (score 0):

If it's of the same origin then there should not be any problem in showing a popup or a notification when an event is fired from the iFrame.
You can access the element or the button which fires the event using the parent iFrame.

Following is an example for you to consider

```
<iframe id="some-iframe" src="something.com">
   <button id="some-button"></button>
</iframe>

using jQuery : $("#some-iframe #some-button").on("click", function(){
   console.log("I fired an event from iFrame");
});
```

Hope this helps.
Let us know if we can be of help any further :)